# Как задать цвет и размер текста одновременно? Tailwind

Tags: tailwindcss

В документации [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) есть описание как задать [цвет](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color) и [размер](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size) текста, но проблема в том, что одновременно задать цвет и размер текста нельзя, так как два класса будут конфликтовать между собой

Например `'text-size-5 text-black-24'`

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой есть выход из данной ситуации?

Comment: Простите, а что за цвет text-black-24, там такого нет, есть только text-black

Comment: Чтобы изменить размер текста нужно использовать такие классы как: text-base, text-lg, text-xl и т.п.

Comment: Эти цвета и размеры кастомные, их можно настроить в config  tailwindcss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё работает как надо, но [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) сортирует и удаляет классы не правильно. Когда я посмотрел в отладчик браузера, я увидел что сборка удаляет `text-size-5`

[Здесь](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/discussions/88) подробное описание проблемы и ее решение